# How I can make Pure CSS3 Smooth Drop-Down Menu in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I am making a bootstrap wordpress theme and I have a problem about adding pure smooth drop-down menu effect for primary menu [like this example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-drop-down-menu) such as it does not seem to work properly after clicked "M logo" to open drop-down menu. You can check out my theme on this link [for more detail](http://dev.galerigadget.com/)

Here are my CSS classes at the moment:

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
    margin: -1px 0 0 45%;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;

}

.dropdown-menu {
    /* background: url(img/submenu.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 91% 100%; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 153px;
    padding: 1px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #5c4d4a;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;

}

.dropdown-menu li a {
    display: block;
    background: url(img/submenu.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 104% 108%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li a:focus {
    background: url(img/submenu.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 104% 108%;
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff428bca', endColorstr='#ff357ebd', GradientType=0);
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu ul { 

list-style: none; 

}
```

Comment: can you please post a fiddle or html part so we can test. In your example link, its not clear though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The salient features required are:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav li:hover .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The float:left is a furfy, it is over-ridden by position:absolute;

Comment: Thanks its fixed now please recheck those link again. Last thing, how about make show drop-down menu without click only just hover the pointer to "M logo"?